# What is the correct way of creating an associative array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm a PHP guy, and in PHP I would do something like the following:

```
$variable = array('0001'=>'value1', '0010'=>'value2');
```

I'm pretty new to VB.NET, so how do I translate the above code to VB.NET?

I think I have to use a dictionary:

```
Dim variable As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
variable.Add("0001", "value1")
variable.Add("0010", "value2")
```

Is this the correct way of doing it or should I use something else for this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a way, or if you prefer a one-liner way of initialization, you can do this:

```
Dim variable As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From { {"0001", "value1"}, {"0010", "value2"} }
```

As far as which is the better one, it's more a matter of coding standard, and/or personal preference.

Considering what kind of container to use, you should use only those from [System.Collection.Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) unless you are forced otherwise. And Dictionary is the default associative container. You can see the alternatives (SortedDictionary for example), if it matches more your use case.

Comment: any alternative one-liner or linq version?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Collection*:

```
Dim var As New Collection
var.Add("vakue1", "0001")
var.Add("value2", "0010")
```

Loop through all with:

```
For Each v As String In var

Next
```

For other ways of treating items, look at the sample in *[Collection(Of T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx.)* ([MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network)).

Comment: What's the advantage of using a collection over using a dictionary?

Comment: @PeeHaa Dictionary is generic, so dictionary is better. Collection is an older class and is not usually recommended for new code.

Comment: But it has methods, that are missing in the dictionary