# how to defince three dimensional array whose index is string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i want to display country, state and city name. These values are retrieved from a database. if the country name doesn't exist then only city and state name will display. If city and state name doesn't exist then only country name will display, as shown below:

```
country = totalno
country/state = totalno
country/state/city = totalno
```

I am saving these values in three dimensional array, but I don't know how to achieve this.
i want my array like this myarray(country,state,city)=1. but can't assign string on index. 
Is there any way to achieve this or any other way to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Would a collection suit your purpose? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112495/what-is-the-correct-way-of-creating-an-associative-array-in-vb-net

Comment: no i have tried collection but no succeeded. actually my array may sometimes in this format country/state and sometime only country so there should be atleast three index for values not two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a 3-dimensional array, you can have a dictionary with a composite index instead. Example keys:

```
USA
USA/OH
Canada/ON/Toronto
```

If a key is missing, you can leave a slash to account for cases when state = country or city (which is rare, but theoretically possible). So to avoid confusion, leave it like this:

```
USA//
USA/OH/
Canada/ON/Toronto
```

It is better than a 3-dimensional array in a sense that you only store the entries you need. And better than a `Dictionary(Of Dictionary(Of Dictionary...` for maintainability purposes.