# Multi depth array in .NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have been trying to do that for the last hour and still can get it to work.
I'm trying to create a multi depth array. Let me explain myslef.

```
Boss
    Manager
        Employee
        Employee
        Employee
    Manager
        Employee
        Employee
        Employee
Boss
    Manager
        Employee
        Employee
        Employee
    Manager
        Employee
        Employee
        Employee
Boss
    Manager
        Employee
        Employee
        Employee
    Manager
        Employee
        Employee
        Employee
```

and they must have a label, here it would be Boss, Manager or Employee's name.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use this approach. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23228752/897326

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to defince three dimensional array whose index is string in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226016/how-to-defince-three-dimensional-array-whose-index-is-string-in-vb-net)

Comment: What are members types? Boss, Manager, Employee or int or ... ?

Comment: I dont really get it. Put 1 string with a / for each level ? Boss, manager & employee are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I managed to do this:

```
Public Class sousdir
    Public name As String
    Public services As New List(Of String)
End Class

Public Class direction
    Public name As String
    Public sousdirs As New List(Of sousdir)
End Class

Dim directions As New List(Of direction)

directions.Add(New direction)
directions(0).name = "Direction 1"
directions(0).sousdirs.Add(New sousdir)
directions(0).sousdirs(0).name = "Sous Direction 1"
directions(0).sousdirs(0).services.Add("Service 1")
directions(0).sousdirs(0).services.Add("Service 2")
directions(0).sousdirs(0).services.Add("Service 3")
directions(0).sousdirs.Add(New sousdir)
directions(0).sousdirs(1).name = "Sous Direction 2"
directions(0).sousdirs(1).services.Add("Service 1")
directions(0).sousdirs(1).services.Add("Service 2")
...
```

With result formatting
[image: Result]

How this will help some people

Answer (score 0):

Might be better just to have a class that represent a hierarchy of a person with a list of people underneath them. Personally, a multidepth array can be a bit complicated especially for the person that is going to maintain the code.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim bosses As New List(Of Hierarchy)

    bosses.Add(New Hierarchy)
    bosses(0).Person = New Person
    bosses(0).Person.Name = "Boss"

    bosses(0).Childs.Add(New Hierarchy)
    bosses(0).Childs(0).Person = New Person
    bosses(0).Childs(0).Person.Name = "Manager"

    bosses(0).Childs(0).Childs.Add(New Hierarchy)
    bosses(0).Childs(0).Childs(0).Person = New Person
    bosses(0).Childs(0).Childs(0).Person.Name = "Employee"

    bosses(0).Childs(0).Childs.Add(New Hierarchy)
    bosses(0).Childs(0).Childs(1).Person = New Person
    bosses(0).Childs(0).Childs(1).Person.Name = "Employee"

    For Each boss In bosses
        Console.WriteLine(boss.Person.Name)

        For Each manager In boss.Childs
            Console.WriteLine("   " & manager.Person.Name)

            For Each employee In manager.Childs
                Console.WriteLine("      " & employee.Person.Name)
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub

Class Hierarchy
    Public Person As Person
    Public Childs As New List(Of Hierarchy)
End Class

Class Person
    Public Name As String
End Class
```